# How to get a form-row in jquery-script(Symfony)

Tags: jquery, symfony

My problem is :
i want the input of the row 1 of the form change its background-color when this input is keydown(with jquery)(.html.twig file),
i have to do like this:

```html
<script>
$('#input's id').keydown(change the color)
</script>
{{ form(form) }}
```

But how to get the input's id?

this is ajout.html.twig file:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src=" {{ asset('jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}" language="javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#examenBundle_chauffeur_cin").keydown(function(){ //chauffeur :name of the controller,cin name of the child

             $('#examenBundle_chauffeur_cin').css('background','red');

        })

    })

</script>
<input>
{{ form(form) }}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add css class to your form field like so:

```
$builder->add('some_field', TextType::class, 
    [
      'attr' => ['class' => 'some_css_class'],
    ]
)
```

And then target that field, or fields in jQuery by its css class, so instead:

```
<script>
  $('#input's id').keydown(change the color)
</script>
```

You could do:

```
<script>
  $('.some_css_class').keydown(change the color)
</script>
```